# Regex to match anything with href="" but between two other tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I already have this Regex pattern that checks for every `href=""` in my document:

```
\(href\s*=\s*(?:"|')(.*?)(?:"|'))
```

Now I want it to match all `href`s ONLY in between `<a` and `</a>` tags, with other parameters still allowed in between.

**Do not match:**

```
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
```

**Match:**

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/"></a>

<a class="re" href="http://www.w3schools.com/"></a>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" class="re">This is a link</a>
```

Thanks in advance, I've not been able to solve this problem as of yet.

Comment: Try to add an example of how you have tried to do it. Or search for a more general solution on the web i.e. how to match regex string that appears before X and after Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Due to the limitation of language classes (regular, stack), this can't be done 100%. But a close approximation is:

`<a\b[^>]*\shref="([^"]*)"`

Or, if you use named subexpressions:

`<a\b[^>]*\shref=(?P<QUOTE>["'])(?P<URL>.*?)(?P=QUOTE)`

Which will also handle apostrophe-delimited attributes.

The last example can also be rewritten as:

`<a\b[^>]*\shref=(["'])(.*?)(\1)`

but remember to use the **second** subexpression, not the first one.

It wasn't clear whether you want to grab the name of the link, but if you do, whichever regex you choose, you can add a simple appendix to get the name. For example, for the named subexpressions:

`<a\b[^>]*\shref=(?P<QUOTE>["'])(?P<URL>.*?)(?P=QUOTE)[^>]*>(?P<NAME>.*?)</a>`

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated what I need it for beforehand. I want to find all links on a HTML document and add something before it e.g. href="http://google.com" becomes href="http://website.com?url=http://google.com". Once again, I excuse for the lack of information. It's my first time on this website. Could you help me find a solution for my exact problem?

Comment: Simply put more parentheses around your chosen regex and perform a replacement. Something like `$result = preg_replace('~(<a\b[^>]*\shref=")([^"]*)(")~igs', '\1http://www.website.com?url=\2\3', $page);`

Comment: This does not always seem to work. I'm assuming it has to do with `'` characters that some websites use instead of `"`. `~(<a\b[^>]*\shref="|<a\b[^>]*\shref=')([^"]*)("|')~igs` looks right but must still have an error.

Comment: Use the named-subexpressions version then. That handles both delimiters.